# can't understand why parentNode.removeChild doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I am new at this and i am trying to understand few stuff.
well, this is my HTML code:

```js
var counter = 0;

function addMore() {
  counter++;
  var newFields = document.getElementById('dupDiv').cloneNode(true);
  newFields.id = 'dupDiv' + counter;
  newFields.name = 'dupDiv' + counter;
  newFields.style.display = 'block';

  var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
  insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields, insertHere);
  document.getElementById('test').value = newFields.name;
}
window.onload = addMore();
```

```html
<table id="mainTable" style="width: 700" align="center" dir="rtl">
  <tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="2">
      <form method="post" name="f1">
        <table align="right" width="600px">
          <tbody id="dupDiv" style="display:none;">
            <tr>
              <td class="a1"><input type="text" value="pp" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="a1">
                <input type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" value="DELETE" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <span id="writeroot"></span>
          <tr>
            <td class="a1">
              <input type="button" onclick="addMore()" value="ADD MORE" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the code is working but it deletes only the button.
And i want it to delete all the tbody that is created.
( I mean that i want to delete the specific tbody that the button was clicked at)

And if it is possible i would like an explanation about parentNode in my code and to what element its connected every time.

**This is not the whole code so some element may be missing

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to delete anything.  It appears to clone a node, insert that into the document and then clear an input field.  What part of the code did you not think was working?

Comment: You also have illegal HTML.  You can't have `<tr></tr><span></span>`.  That is not legal.  You can't have `<tr>` elements outside of your `<tbody>`.

Comment: If you click on the delete button - > with the onclick function it suppose to delete the whole tbody (the delete button and the text box) but it delets only the button. It is not in the function of addMore, but i thought that it might help understand the problem.

Comment: OK, I now see you're using inline onclick handler code to do the delete.  Eeeck.  Horrible practice.  I will look at that now.

Comment: Oh, i thought because its a short code it won't be a problem to do it like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your click handler appears to be this:

```
onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"
```

`this` will be the button that was clicked.

`this.parentNode` will be the containing `<td>`.

`this.parentNode.parentNode` will the containing `<tr>`.

So you're getting the containing row and telling that row to remove the containing `<td>`.  That's what your code instructs the browser to do.

If what you're trying to do is to delete the containing `<tbody>` element, you need to go up the hierarchy further to get to the actual `<tbody>` element and to the `<table>` element itself.

```
var tbody = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
tbody.parentNode.removeChild(tbody);
```

---

Whenever I see the need for reaching up the parent hierarchy like this with multiple `.parentNode` references, the code looks brittle to me (it could break easily if slight changes were made to the HTML).  For example this code would make if the `<input>` tag was simply enclosed in a `<div>` just to facilitate formatting or layout.  As such, I try to avoid this type of code.  In this case, you could use a small utility function that looks up the parent hierarchy for a parent type of parent and then that would continue to work even if minor changes were made to the HTML.  This is probably how I could write this code:

```
// search up the parent chain for a particular tag type
function closestParentTag(start, tag) {
    var found;
    tag = tag.toLowerCase();
    while (start && start !== document.documentElement && !(found = start.tagName.toLowerCase() === tag)) {
        start = start.parentNode;
    }
    return found ? start : null;
}


function removeCurrentBody(elem) {
    var tbody = closestParentTag(elem, "tbody");
    if (tbody) {
        tbody.parentNode.removeChild(tbody);
    }
}
```

---

Also, change:

```
window.onload = addMore();
```

to:

```
window.onload = addMore;
```

The way you had it was calling the function immediately.  Instead, you want to assign a function reference so it can be called LATER.

When, in your code, you refer to a function by named only without parens after it such as:

var foo = addMore;

That is assigning a function reference to the variable `foo`.  You can think of it like a pointer to the function `addMore`.  Nothing is called right now.  You've just assigned a pointer to the function to another variable.  This is how you pass or assign functions so they can be called later by some other agent.

When, in your code you have parens after a function name, that function is executed immediately.

```
 var foo = addMore();
```

This executes `addMore()` immediately and assigns the return result from that function to the variable `foo`.

Comment: Exactly. @user3478552, `onload` will call `addMore`, which is a function **reference**. When you pass `addMore()` in its "called" form to `onload`, you're actually passing the **return value** to `onload`. That's not what you want.

Comment: This thing is working fine for me. But my question was about the delete button that is not fully working

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed my code, but unfortunately, this was not my question. please run the snippet and you will see that the delete button is not working good.

Comment: See the comments I added to your question.

Comment: @user3478552 - this may not solve your entire problem (I don't yet understand your entire problem so I've asked you some questions as comments to your question), but this change does need to be made and is likely part of a solution.

Comment: i answered your comment. the problem is when i run the onclick function in the delete button. It should delete the whole tbody - textbox and button, but it delets only the tbody. Do you know why its happening?

Comment: @user3478552 - OK, I've put in an explanation for your current code and a possible solution.

Comment: @user3478552 - I added an more robust code suggestion to my answer.